# Simple Mail Server on Arch Linux

Tags: linux, smtp, email, imap, arch-linux

Looking through all sorts of tutorials I have not yet found one that I can use to set up a simple mail server for non-virtual users. I don't want to support any sort of virtual users, just two real users set up on the machine.

Do you know of any tutorials that explain how to do this?

I have a domain set up where I have access to the DNS settings, and I would like an imap and smtp server running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be what your looking for.

[Courier MTA on the Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Courier_MTA)

Comment: That talks about virtual users, and I don't know enough about the configuration files on how to use real users instead

Comment: Ok, using that tutorial I finally worked it out, thanks!